# C++ Circular dependency due to enum class nested

Tags: c++, class, enums, nested, circular-dependency

I have a circular dependency created by a nested enum.

```
class A
{
    enum class A_enum {};

    void method_which_uses_class_B() {}
}

class B
{
    void method_which_uses_A_enum() {}
}
```

That gives you an idea of the overall structure.

Specifically, I have the enum class defined in this way:

```
... file containing class A

class A
{
    enum class A_enum
    {
        ITEM_A, ITEM_B
    };

    // then the rest of A goes here
}

// in my main code file

#include "class B file"
#include "class A file"

... code
```

The solution therefore would be to move the enum class out of `class A` and put code/files/include's in the correct order to prevent the problem.

But it's rather nice to have the enum class nested inside `class A` for my purposes. Is there a way of pre-defining that there will be a `class A` and what the enum inside that class will be? I tried the following, but it didn't work because I was defining the class twice:

```
class A;

enum class A::A_enum
{
    contenta, contentb
};
```

or

```
class A
{
    enum class A_enum {...};
}
```

then

```
class A
{
    // the rest of it
    // obviously doesn't work because already defined class A
}
```

Comment: Can you show us where the circular dependency occurs? Is it in the body of the methods or in the arguments?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to handle this situation is to implement `A::method_which_uses_class_B()` after the definition of `class B`.

```
class A
{
    enum class A_enum {};

    void method_which_uses_class_B();
};

class B
{
    void method_which_uses_A_enum() {}
};

void A::method_which_uses_class_B()
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Forward Declarations can solve this problem:

```
class A;
class B;

class A {
    public:
        enum class A_enum {};
        void method_which_uses_class_B();
};

class B {
    public:
        void method_which_uses_A_enum();
};

void A::method_which_uses_class_B() {
    A::A_enum instance_of_a_enum;
    A instance_of_a;
    B instance_of_b;
}

void B::method_which_uses_A_enum() {
    A::A_enum instance_of_a_enum;
    A instance_of_a;
    B instance_of_b;
}
```